# Передача json из laravel в js

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

Не передается json.
Код контроллера:

```
use Response;
use Request;
use DB;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\AddEvent;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
    $even = DB::table('All_Events')->select('Title', 'Location')->get();
    $data = ['Title'=>'Все мероприятия'];

    if (Request::ajax()){
      dd($even);
      return Response::json($even);
    }else{
      return view('index', $data);
    }
  }
}
```

Код запроса:

```
function test() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'App/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php',
    success: function (data) {
        arr = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(arr);
    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   function test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'АДРЕСС РОУТА (ROUTE) где вызывается данный контроллер',
        success: function (data) {
            arr = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(arr);
        }
     });
    }
```

Параметр url - не путь на файл, а путь на страницу где выполняется контроллер `HomeController` и его метод `index`

Попробуйте что-то такое:

1. Замените вашу функцию на это:

КОД:

```
function test() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/',
            success: function (data) {
                arr = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(arr);
            }
         });
        }
```

2. В файле (для laravel 5) который находиться в `app/Http/routes.php` напишите нечто такое:

   `Route::get('/','HomeController@index');`

Так же вам понадобятся данные ссылки:

- [Маршрутизация в Laravel 5](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/routing)
- [Контроллеры в Laravel 5](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/controllers)